# Turning a character vector into an empty list with names from the character vector

Tags: r, list, function, tidyverse, purrr

given a character vector:

```
myvec <- c("one", "two", "three")
```

I would like to turn it into a list such that names of the elements of the list come from the character vector and the list itself is empty. Note that I do not know the length of the character vector *a priori*. I need this because later on I programatically fill in each element of this list.

My desired output:

```
str(mylist)

$one
NULL

$two
NULL

$three
NULL
```

I came up with this:

```
turnList <- function(x){map(as.list(set_names(x)), ~NULL)}
```

And it works and all is well but I have a feeling it can be done more simply...? Solutions with purrr and tidyverse in general would be ideal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Base R** No packages are used.

```
Map(function(x) NULL, myvec)
```

**2) gsubfn** At the expense of using a package we can slightly shorten it further:

```
library(gsubfn)
fn$Map(. ~ NULL, myvec)
```

**3) purrr** or using purrr (at the expense of a package and a few more characters in code length).  This is similar to the approach in the question but simplifies it by eliminating the `as.list` which is not needed.

```
library(purrr)
map(set_names(myvec), ~ NULL)
```

### Note

A comment below this answer points out that `NULL` can be replaced with `{}`. 
That will save two characters and applies to any of the above.

Comment: Accepted the answer as it is using map, seems more straightforward and makes me feel better about direction in which I went to figure this out. Thanks everyone for good ideas!

Answer (score 1):

```
setNames(vector("list", length(myvec)), myvec)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `vector`

```
setNames(vector("list", length = length(myvec)), myvec)

#$one
#NULL

#$two
#NULL

#$three
#NULL
```

Or `replicate`

```
setNames(replicate(length(myvec), NULL), myvec)
```

Comment: I guess I beat you by 7 seconds this time :).